# Angular show product Gallery in modal

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, modal-dialog, image-gallery

following on from a previous question, I need to display my product gallery within a modal here at col-xs-5:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="product-details-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">×</button>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
          <product-gallery></product-gallery>
        </div>
        <!--/.col-xs-5-->
        <div class="col-xs-7 modal-details">
          <div class="modal-details-inner">
            <p>{{store.selected.name}}</p>
            <p>{{store.selected.description}}</p>
          </div><!--/.modal-details-inner-->
        </div><!--/.xs-7-->
      </div><!--/.modal-content-->
    </div><!--/.modal-dialog-->
  </div>
```

Every other piece of information is being pulled from my json file and displayed fine. But the Gallery only works when I put a ng-repeat within the modal, which in turn obviously shows all the gallery images for all products.

How would I just show the gallery for that particular product item? I have added the code below…

http://plnkr.co/edit/ouKSSnnAnTZvLyyePOXS?p=preview

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array of gallery images can be access in the `store.selected` object:

```
<div class='gallery' ng-show="store.selected.images.length">
  ...
</div>
```

Here is an update of your plunker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/1mIl9tiK320kzFXyZqsV?p=preview